# Can WINE handle ECC certificates?

Tags: ssl-certificate, wine, elliptic-curve

I have an application that supposedly runs well under Mono, but is having some problems on my system. In the meantime, I tried running it through WINE after using winetricks to install the proper version of .NET (`winetricks dotnet452`).

This worked great! The application hits Github to check for updates and manages the SSL/TLS connection flawlessly. Elsewhere while using it, it attempts to access another website, https://themoose.co.uk, but fails with an SSL/TLS error. The only reasonable difference I could find between that site and Github was that it uses an ECC cert as opposed to Github's more traditional RSA cert.

I also saw these lines in WINE's console output:

```
fixme:secur32:schan_get_cipher_algid Don't know CALG for encryption algorithm 2, returning 0
fixme:secur32:schan_imp_get_max_message_size Returning 1 << 14.
fixme:secur32:schan_get_cipher_algid Don't know CALG for encryption algorithm 2, returning 0
```

Googling these messages doesn't return anything useful.

The conclusion I am drawn to is that WINE doesn't support new ECC certificates, but I do not see that limitation documented anywhere! Am I going crazy, or is this an oversight in the documentation somewhere?